# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 - Stuck at "Starting Diagnostic Tools..."

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, diagnostic-tools

I've been having an issue with Visual Studio wherein the Diagnostic Tools doesn't start at all.

When I begin debugging, the Diagnostic Tools window would show (as expected) but it just stays at "Starting Diagnostic Tools..." and nothing happens.

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42590076) that some applications (possibly an AV) is preventing the required processes from executing but I don't see anything being blocked.

Details about the project:

1. It's an ASP.Net web application (Web Forms).
2. We have Entity Framework 6 installed.
3. We have DevExpress installed (might be the culprit?)

I also tried creating/opening a different project (a console application) and the same thing happens (nothing)

[image]

What I've done so far based on suggestions from other forums/questions:

1. Restarted VS.
2. Repaired VS.
3. Restarted the server.
4. Deleted the *.suo file.
5. Made sure Use Managed Compatibility Mode is unchecked in the
   options.
6. Made sure Use Native Compatibility Mode is unchecked in the options.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/135637/profiler-stuck-at-starting-diagnostics-session.html) and it's going to be fixed in the incoming release. I just disabled Diagnostic tools for now to make my VS work (Options - Debugging - General - Diagnostic tools).

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Resharper (not uninstalling) got the tool working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues with a C++ project in Visual Studio 2017. Have not yet found a way to fix the problem, but have found a bypass.

Got to the Performance Profiler..., select the Performance Wizard and then select CPU Sampling instead of CPU Usage. This will give you almost the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue with Visual Studio 2015 immediately after an ESET Smart Security update.

After disabling its firewall (rather than AV protection), the project started up.  Strangely, re-enabling its firewall led to no further issues.

As per the thread you already looked at - there could be a number of Antivirus & Firewall applications blocking it.  I certainly saw no logs (or reference to Visual Studio specific executables) or alerts to point at ESET as the culprit in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you meant by 'Restarting the server', but what worked for me was killing the processes ServiceHub.Host.Node.x86.exe